# which method to use after adding a message in JSQmessagesViewController

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

After I add and receive a message to the JSQMessage collection, which method am I supposed to call to refresh the view and render the new message? `self.finishReceivingMessage()` or `self.collectionView!.reloadData()`?

Which is more performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the following:

`self.finishReceivingMessage()`

this will automatically reload the collection view.

Comment: it is incredible, this library is so great and at the same time, it has a poor documentation :( things simple as this, I can't find in its docs